# Show $R=\{(x, y)$ : $|x|<1,|y|<1\}$ is an open set.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Show that an open rectangular region $R=\{(x, y)$ : $|x|<1,|y|<1\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is an open set.

I assume the metric is the usual one. I do know that, "A subset $M$ of a metric space $X$ is said to be open if it contains a ball(open) about each of its points". But I couldn't manage to construction the balls. I guess $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}$ sequence can help in this construction.

I was wondering: could changing the metric can also change the open characterization also?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $R$ is the open unit ball for the norm  $\|\|_{\infty}$ so it's open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $|x|,|y|<1$ and let $r$ be the shortest distance to the edge of the square. Then the circle centred at $(x,y)$ of radius $r$ is contained in the interior.

Another approach would be to note that $f,g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y):=|x|$ and $g(x,y):=|y|$ are both continuous. Since the continuous preimage of an open set is open, we have that $$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|,|y|<1\}=f^{-1}(-\infty,1)\cap g^{-1}(-\infty,1)$$ is the intersection of two open sets, and therefore open.

On your question about how the 'open characterization' depends on the metric: the collection of open sets is called a [*topology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology) and does indeed depend on the metric. Two metrics that give the same open sets are said to be [*topologically equivalent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics). In the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$, the 'usual' metrics $$d_1((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)):=|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|,$$ $$d_2((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)):=(|x_1-x_2|^2+|y_1-y_2|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}},$$ and $$d_\infty((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)):=\text{max}\{|x_1-x_2|,|y_1-y_2|\}$$ all have the same open sets. You can see this by checking that there exists $c,C>0$ for which $cd_1(x,y)\leq d_2(x,y)\leq Cd_1(x,y)$ for each pair of points $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and similarly for comparing the other metrics. The collection of open sets that arises from these metrics is called the [*Euclidean topology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_topology), which is the one we are all familiar with.

Comment: Nice Answer @VeryForgetfulFunctor. I like the preimage logic very much.

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory Thank you! Please consider accepting an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon = \min(1-|x|, 1-|y|)$ and consider the open ball about $(x,y)$ of radius $\epsilon$.

Need to show that this is contained in $R$.

Consider the (open) square region $Q$ whose sides are of length $2\epsilon$ that is centered at $(x,y)$.  This square region is completely contained in $R$.

Further, the open ball of radius $\epsilon$, centered at $(x,y)$ is completely contained in $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $(x,y) \in R$ and let $\delta = \operatorname{min}(1-|x|,1 -|y|)$. Then $B_{\delta}(x,y) \subset R$.

If you have a metric you define the topology in the most cases to be induced by the metric, i.e. open metric balls are open. Openness is a question of topology and the topology can be defined independently of any metric. If you change the metric the topology changes also in general. Take for example the metric $d(x,y) = 1$ if $x \neq y$ and $d(x,y) = 0$ if $x = y$. Then the $\frac{1}{2}$-balls are points, and therefore the topology is discrete.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that :

$$R = ]-1, 1[ \times ]-1, 1[$$
then $R$ is open.

Comment: So, you are suggesting to use the product space and its basis, but that wasn't introduced in that course.

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory Open intervals are open in $\mathbb{R}$ (with the metric $d(x,y):=|x-y|$ that gives the 'usual' topology). Then $R=(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\equiv\mathbb{R}^2$ (product of open sets is open in the *product topology* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology). The product topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the same as its Euclidean topology, so its open sets are obtained by the topologically equivalent metrics $d_1$, $d_2$, $d_\infty$ given in my answer.